# What are the rules for default generated copy constructors being constant expressions?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

For struct `A` below the compiler default generates copy constructors. Both gcc and clang seem to define these as `constexpr` ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SsnJMTMKAX8lqiDl)). Now I wonder what are the rules for default generated constructors being constant expressions?

```
struct A
{
    constexpr A() : i(0) {}
    explicit constexpr A( int v ) : i(v) {}
    constexpr int get() const { return i; }
private:
    int const  i;
}; 
int main() {
    constexpr A a( 3 );
    constexpr A b= a;
    constexpr A c{ a };
    constexpr int i1= a.get();
    constexpr int i2= b.get();
    constexpr int i3= c.get();
    std::cout << i1 << "  " << i2 << "  " << i3 << '\n';

    constexpr A d{ std::move(c) };
    constexpr int i4= d.get();
    std::cout << i4 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: But there should not be any generated default constructor in the structure you show, as you declare and define it yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think OP meant that the constructors have a default implementation.

Comment: Then perhaps [this constructor (and initializer list) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) could help? Especially the ["Explanation section](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Explanation) and the [LiteralType concept reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType).

Comment: Note that `constexpr A d{ std::move(c) };` calls `A`'s copy constructor, not move constructor, since `c` is `const` and `move(c)` cannot bind to `A&&`.

Comment: By the way, the "live demo" code is small enough to be fully pasted into the question body. Don't force us to go to external sites to see your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler can generate the default constructor as `constexpr`. See [[class.ctor#7]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.ctor#7):

> If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the requirements of a constexpr constructor, the implicitly-defined default constructor is constexpr.

However, classes that aren't literal types can still have `constexpr` constructors, it just can't be defaulted. See [[dcl.fct.def#default-3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.def#default-3):

> An explicitly-defaulted function that is not defined as deleted may be declared constexpr only if it would have been implicitly declared as constexpr.
>   If a function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration, it is implicitly considered to be constexpr if the implicit declaration would be.

Comment: I suspect the OP meant "defaulted constructors", not "default constructors", since in the example given it's true the "compiler generates" defaulted copy and move constructors, but not the default constructor, which is user-provided. So [class.copy.ctor]/12 would also be relevant.

Comment: @aschepler I chose the default constructor as an example, but the same logic should apply to [copy/move constructors as well](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.ctor#12).